# What happens when a HTTP request uses different browser headers?

Tags: http, iis

I'm trying to understand how an IIS server handles different browsers in the header of an HTTP request.

The situation is that I have some load tests set up that fire off HTTP requests to an IIS server, constructing them and sending them over the wire. My code allows me to specify the browser in the header, but I'm not sure what that would actually change.

So what does IIS do with that particular information in the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i am aware IIS doesn't actually do anything with the header.

You can create rules to explicitly handle a type of browser, this is pretty useful if you block traffic from countries but you still want to allow bots for example.

Its useful to also have this information in Log Files too